# I am unable to write test class please help me out

Tags: apex, unit-test

```
 public void sendComplaintsCaseWaitingForSevenDaysNotification(List<Case> newList){
        Id complaintsRecordType = Schema.SObjectType.Case.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Complaints').getRecordTypeId();
        Id complaintsACARecordType = Schema.SObjectType.Case.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Complaints ACA').getRecordTypeId();
        Id complaintsExecManualRecordType = Schema.SObjectType.Case.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Complaints Exec Manual').getRecordTypeId();
        Id complaintsSummaryRecordType = Schema.SObjectType.Case.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Complaints Summary Case').getRecordTypeId();
        Id governmentRegulatorRecordType = Schema.SObjectType.Case.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Government Regulator').getRecordTypeId();
        Id tradcomplaintsRecordType = Schema.SObjectType.Case.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Trade Complaints').getRecordTypeId();
        List<Case> newCases = [Select id,Origin,Status,Language__c,Contact.Name,Contact.FirstName,Send_Acknowledgement_Email__c, ContactEmail, CaseNumber,Customer_Email__c,RecordTypeId, Customer_Name__c,Customer_First_Name__c, OwnerId, Owner.Name from Case where id IN: newList ];
        for(Case c : newCases){
            if((c.RecordTypeId == complaintsRecordType || c.RecordTypeId == complaintsACARecordType || c.RecordTypeId == complaintsExecManualRecordType || c.RecordTypeId == complaintsSummaryRecordType || c.RecordTypeId == governmentRegulatorRecordType) && c.Origin != 'Cabin Crew Complaints' &&  (c.ContactEmail!=null || c.Customer_Email__c != null) && c.Status == 'Waiting for Documents' ){
                ComplaintsEmailNotificationHandler.sendWaitingForCustSevenDaysNotification(c);
            }
            if((c.RecordTypeId == tradcomplaintsRecordType) && c.Origin != 'Cabin Crew Complaints' &&  (c.ContactEmail!=null || c.Customer_Email__c != null) && c.Status == 'Waiting for Documents'){
                ComplaintsEmailNotificationHandler.sendWaitingForCustSevenDaysNotificationTrade(c);
            }
        } 
    }
```

Comment: HI krishna, welcome to SFSE. Please take a moment to scroll through the [tour] and read [ask]. What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? If you don't know how to write unit tests at all, there are very good Trailhead modules out there to teach you the basics. If you are stuck on a specific aspect, please **[edit]** your post and you may find people here willing to help.

Answer (score 2):

The current code is hard to read which makes writing the test harder (and makes future maintenance much harder). If this is new code, I would start by refactoring it before working on the test so what is going on is clearer e.g.:

```
public void sendComplaintsCaseWaitingForSevenDaysNotification(List<Case> newList){

    Set<Id> customerRtIds = new Set<Id>{
        rtId('Complaints'),
        rtId('Complaints ACA'),
        ...
    };

    Set<Id> tradeRtIds = new Set<Id>{
        rtId('Trade Complaints')
    };

    for (Case c : newCases) {
        if (c.Origin != 'Cabin Crew Complaints'
                && (c.ContactEmail != null || c.Customer_Email__c != null)
                && c.Status == 'Waiting for Documents'
                ) {
            if (customerRtIds.contains(c.RecordTypeId)) {
                ComplaintsEmailNotificationHandler.sendWaitingForCustSevenDaysNotification(c);
            } else if (tradeRtIds.contains(c.RecordTypeId)) {
                ComplaintsEmailNotificationHandler.sendWaitingForCustSevenDaysNotificationTrade(c);
            }
        }
    } 
}

@TestVisible
private static Id rtId(String name) {
    // Better to use the new'ish developer name API here
    return Schema.SObjectType.Case.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get(name).getRecordTypeId();
}
```